# How does a mobile site get to know which mobile operator I'm using?

Tags: privacy, mobile-phone, tracking, advertisements, telecommunication

I was browsing internet from my mobile, and I noticed that mobile site were showing ads specific to the  mobile operator that I was using. I switched the sim card of a different mobile operator and browse the same sites again and now this time they were showing ads specific to latter mobile operator.

so how does a site get to know which mobile operator I'm using ?

Answer (score 6):

If you are browsing using your operator's network (and not Wi-Fi) they could just check which company owns the IP address that you are assigned when accessing the site. It's pretty easy to do.

Click on [this](http://ip-lookup.net/) to get information about the IP address you are using. As you can see it tells you which company actually uses the IP address in the host section.